# i have fixed image and texview in toolbar. Now its not showing menus

Tags: android, xml, menuitem, submenu

- why not show menuItem on click Image and TextView.
         please anyone help me for showing my menusItem.
             (i using  app:actionLayout="@layout/login_icon_design").
     when we remove app:actionLayout tag so menus are come.

  ```
  //dashboard.xml file
  ```

  enter code here

  //login_icon_design.xml

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/qcId"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingLeft="0dp"
      android:text="Active"
      android:textColor="@color/button_green"
      android:textSize="9dp" />
  ```

  //DashboardActivity.java

  ```
    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
          final Menu m = menu;
          final MenuItem mitem = menu.findItem(R.id.button);
          TextView qcId= (TextView) mitem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.qcId);
          SharedPreferences pref=this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
          String refCode=pref.getString("refCode",null);
          qcId.setText(refCode);

          Intent intent = getIntent();
          String str2 = intent.getStringExtra("balance");
          menu.findItem(R.id.bal).setTitle("Avl. Bal. \u20B9" +str2);
          return true;
      }
      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

          int id = item.getItemId();

          if(id == R.id.bal) {

          } else if(id == R.id.profile){
              Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          } else if (id == R.id.logout){
              Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          } else if(id == R.id.event) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          } else if(id == R.id.history) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  ```

Comment: you have to create custom tool bar .but seems you are adding it  to default menu file attribute .you could do it through custom menu and tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these few lines

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```